# Software to remove tourists from one scene, given multiple shots

Tags: gratis, linux, ubuntu, photography

I have a point-and-shoot camera with which I made multiple high-resolution, but not raw images of about the same scene - I didn't use a tripod, so the camera moved slightly.

It is an open place where I want to remove tourists / dogs / cars from.

I have seen [this question from 2012](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/20953/27076) about Photoshop.

I would like to do pretty much, the same, but with [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) software that runs on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04).

Example scene:

- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Budapest-Fishermans-Bastion-2018-12-09-026.jpg
- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Budapest-Fishermans-Bastion-2018-12-09-027.jpg
- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Budapest-Fishermans-Bastion-2018-12-09-028.jpg
- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Budapest-Fishermans-Bastion-2018-12-09-029.jpg
- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Budapest-Fishermans-Bastion-2018-12-09-030.jpg
- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Budapest-Fishermans-Bastion-2018-12-09-031.jpg

Comment: AFAIR there was some article on how to do that with GIMP. Though most of those describe how to do it on a simgle image using the Resynthesize filter. Maybe [this tutorial](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-merge-pictures-in-gimp) on merging images in GIMP could serve as a starting point?

Comment: I know one way ow to do it with gimp. That would, however, easilytake about 30 minutes per scene: (1) Aligning all photos would take about 15min (2) Searching the right crop (3) adjusting colors at the borders. I don't think gimp is the right tool for the job.

Comment: Was just an idea. I know on Android, Almalence's *Better Camera* has that feature. So if replacing your point-and-shoot by an Android device is an option, that would be worth a try (I haven't tried the feature there myself, I just know it was advertized).

Comment: Can't Martin just import his photos to an Android device & run the app?

Comment: I have no conclusive suggestions, but this sounds like something that might be possible with OpenCV, possibly with some pre/post processing using ImageMagick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use median blending. The G'MIC plugin for GIMP has it, or you can use ImageMagick.

```
convert *.jpg -evaluate-sequence median OUT.jpg
```

The images need to be aligned. You can use `align_image_stack`. It's also helpful to use a tripod when taking the pictures.

See Pat David: [Noise Removal in Photos with Median Stacks (GIMP/G'MIC & Imagemagick)](https://patdavid.net/2013/05/noise-removal-in-photos-with-median_6.html)